# MSM site and Better Meta plugin

Tags: multi-site-manager, metadata

How can I get Multisite managed site to work with the [Better Meta](https://ee-garage.com/nsm-better-meta) plugin?

I have templates on one site but how can I get different metadata from the Better Meta options and from channel entries on the second site?

As I am just getting the default meta data from the default site where the template are.

I have tried this for example:

```
{exp:nsm_better_meta:template entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" hide_site_title="{embed:hide_site_title}" robots_index="{embed:robots_index}" site="{msmsite}"}
```

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this issue today and found the solution. The documentation on the NSM Better Meta plugin available on their site is not comprehensive. I only found the solution by perusing through the plugin code myself.

There is a parameter **site_id** which can be set to pull metadata from entries contained under a different MSM site. Just be sure to substitute the **site_short_name** with the **site_id**.

Your code should look something like this:

```
{exp:nsm_better_meta:template entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
                              hide_site_title="{embed:hide_site_title}"
                              robots_index="{embed:robots_index}"
                              site_id="{msmsiteid}"
}
```